# Does someone experienced error 404 slug for /product/

Tags: woocommerce, permalinks

When I sert slug for WooCommerce /product/ then all products in the loop will be generated but clicking on the /product/my-product  will cause a error 404.

I disabled all of the plugins and default theme but still no luck.

I think something in the database is manipulating that.

Any ideas.

Changing slug to /item/ will work

Comment: update permalinks ?

Comment: That was offcourse the first step I also tried - save permalinks but still error 404 - tnx

Comment: check your htaccess for redirections ?

Comment: No luck removed the htacces and build new one

Comment: I cant reproduce this problem with latest wp and woo versions. You can try manual flush - https://www.futurestatemedia.com/en/solving-woocommerce-404-error-on-product-pages/ the example is with cron job but you can run the function without it and check

Comment: Tried above suggestions, but still error 404 on /product/ slug - however the Permalink Manager (plugin not free) reseted all of my permalinks.